# Getting difficulty to write php code in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

My code, 
Using below code ineed to store catlog_id in a session but it is not working

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#catlog").click(function(event) { 
                 var catlog ="<?php $this->session->set_userdata('catlog_id',"+$('.catlog_id').val()+")?>"; 
            });
        });
```

Comment: As @Jpsy mentioned, you're mixing client- and server-code here. If you want to set a PHP session variable / execute a PHP function on button click, post a form or make an Ajax request to the server. If you just want to set a cookie, you don't necessarily need to request the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is executed on the client machine and there is no PHP interpreter there. Any code that you create on the fly through JS must be HTML, CSS, JS. Setting cookies can be done through JS, look for a cookie plugins for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to access client data is to use cookies.

You can store with javascript/jquery data in a cookie and then you can it later access with php $_COOKIE

You can use the firefox plugin firebug to track the cookie changes.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: He has tried to access data from PHP with Jquery. To do this, Cookies are a way to do this. And to controll the cookies firebug is a good tool. You don't think so?

Comment: I agree, cookies are *one* way (not necessarily a *good* way, especially not when the goal is to update a session entry) to exchange data between client and server. But this does not answer why the OP's approach is not working, and also, I do not quite understand the point of tracking cookies with firebug in this context. I don't find this answer clear or helpful at all. But this is just my opinion, so please don't take it personally.